# How to access an element of the Text array in Unity? C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an array of text, is it possible to refer to the names of the array element, and then use the switch to refer to the names, something like this:
 `switch(text.name ){ case: "Photo" action... break; case: "Room" action... break; }`

Is it possible to do this?)

Comment: I have problems with tags, for some reason they are not fixed correctly, I chose C# and Unity 2d tags. Therefore, the C language is not suitable(

Comment: difficult to understant what you want..its unclear.....could you show some code with a concrete sample?

Comment: @Фрэнчи. I have an array: plaintext[] Word_1;, and I want to use the Text titles that I named in unity. The code as I think about it is like this:
public text[] txt;
public void Submit()
{
switch (txt[].name)
{
case: "Photo"
Debug.Log("OK");
break;
case: "Room"
Debug.Log("No");
break;}

Comment: i repeat again its not clear without a concrete code and concrete explanation, text[].name has no sense in c#.... and `i want to use the text titles that i named in unity...` ??

Comment: By `texts` you mean `string[]` or an actual `Text` component? Also the tags Unity2d and Unity3d are synonyms since there actually is no such thing as Unity2D .. it is Unity3D using 2D components and an orthographic camera that's all ..

Answer (score 0):

It's possible like this

```
  switch (text.Name)
  {
    case string name when name == "Photo":
      // some Action
      break;

    case string name when name == "Room":
      // some Action
      break;

    default:
      throw new System.Exception ("Some error");
  }
```

But the question is why don't you just use `if (text.name == "Photo") { ... } else if (text.name == "Room") ...`

Or even better, can you change the source? so instead of using `string` can you use an `enum`? That would help that the compiler could notice you if have a typo.

Edit because of comment:

Perhaps I misunderstood your problem. Is `text` a `string[]`? than you can't use switch at all because you wan't to loop over an array and not to switch between different code paths. Than you need to do something like this

```
foreach (var foo in text)
{
  if (foo == "Photo")
  {
  }
  else if (foo == "Room")
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried as you showed me, but an error occurs: "Text[]" does not contain the definition of "name", and I could not find an available extension method "name" that accepts the type "Text[]" as the first argument (perhaps the using directive or the assembly reference was omitted).

Comment: @JustGhostly Well .. you are iterating over your array right? Of course you do not want to use the switch on the entire array but on elements within it ...